# How to share log4net logger between client and WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, log4net

I'm using log4net in my console application to log different steps and errors during execution. During the processing, the application sends data to a WCF service where the data is used to do some operations.

I would like the client logger setup in my console application to be shared with the WCF service so that I could use it in my WCF service also. Is it possible ?

The log4net  config in client application:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs\\log_" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.\tx\t" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ErrorsAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs\\errorlog_" />
      <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.\tx\t" />
      <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ERROR" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorsAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

In the WCF service:

```
public class SyncService : ISyncService
{
    public ILog log { get; set; }

    public void GetLogger(ILog _log)
    {
        log = _log;
    }
}
```

Interface file:

```
namespace SyncService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISyncService
    {

        [OperationContract]
        void GetLogger(ILog _log);
    }
}
```

And finally in the client application, where I try to pass the logger to the WCF service:

```
// Setup communication with WCF service
SyncService.SyncServiceClient syncclient = new SyncService.SyncServiceClient();

// Pass logger to WCF service
syncclient.GetLogger(log);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot serialized the aspects: Type 'log4net.Core.LogImpl' in assembly
>   'log4net [...]

How can I pass my logger to my WCF service ?

Comment: You want two different processes to share the same logger?  Why don't you just log to the same destination (file, database, etc)?  Just use the same logging configuration in both projects.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that. I would need to copy the log4net configuration section of my app.config (console application) in my web.config file of the WCF service ? Isn't the log filepath specified in the app.config file be wrong because the service is on a web server compared to the console app which is on the client machine ?

Comment: You don't want two processes logging to the same file anyway.  They'll overwrite each other.  Write to the same folder, or a webservice, or a database.  The approach you've tried will definitely **not** work.

Comment: Why wouldn't I want that ? I would like to limit the number of log files the client will have to look if errors happens. That is why I wanted to share the same logger between the two processes. This way when the applications finishes, there is only one log file to look. Of course I don't want the WCF logger to overwrite the client logger, that's why I want to pass the logger to the WCF service so that it continues to write in the same file as the client logger started to write in.

Comment: I said why in my second sentence.  Two processes logging to the same file can overwrite each other.  If you want two processes to log to the same file, have them send their log data to a third process which governs the logging.  You cannot pass a logger like you're trying to do.  It will not work.

Comment: @amy, logging to the same file is no problem as long as you append true configured and a minimal locking strategy. Minimal locking is bad for performance, but it works.